# Add "via %Botname%" to Telegram message caption

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

How to add the following suffix to the message that was sent to the **channel** via my Bot?

[image]

I mean `via @vote` suffix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `via @bot` gets added when sending a [InlineQueryResultArticle](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequeryresultarticle).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to send this message without interacting with the user (I mean only from the Bot)?

Comment: No, the closest you can get is forwarding a message.